# echo $1 = un-quoted spaced string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

I want to send a variable to it but without quotes.

example:

```
 ./script 1 2 3
```

The above will **NOT** work (print **1 2 3**) 
because **1 2 3** is not inside quotes.

I do not want to use quotes. 
because typing quotes takes extra time.

is it **Possible** ?

Comment: Are backslashed spaces acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You could change the script to

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$*"
```

`"$*"` expands to a single string which consists of all the arguments passed to the string, concatenated with a space between each argument. Thus

```
$ ./script 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

But that doesn't pass whatever follows the script name on the command line literally. That would be impossible. For example, multiple spaces get squished together since they were just separating arguments:

```
$ ./script 1  2 3
1 2 3
```

Shell special characters still get expanded.

```
$ ./script 2 * 2
2 bin dev etc home lib lost+found proc run sbin tmp sys usr var 2
$ ./script hello ; world
hello
bash: world: command not found
```

You can't use this to pass a variable to the script without quotes, since what this does is to first split the variable's value at whitespace, then expand wildcard characters that match at least one file name, and finally concatenate the results.

```
$ foo='2  *  2'
$ ./script $foo
2 bin dev etc home lib lost+found proc run sbin tmp sys usr var 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $@
```

produces:

```
$ ./test.sh 1 23 4 5 6
$ 1 23 4 5 6
```